# Ajax Call Issue - faultcode:'sf:INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS'

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

Getting error message -

> faultcode:'sf:INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS', faultstring:'ClassName: no access
>   allowed to this class.',

Please help.

**Note:** "Access of the class is already enabled"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note if you are trying to call a class method from a Custom Button using AJAX then -

1. Class needs to be a **Global** class
2. Method you intend to call from the javascript must be a **Webservice**
   Method
3. Access to the Class has been provided via security button/link

This should resolve your issue.